# How to hide "Trackback" on paginated comments

Tags: comments, comments-template

**My Setup:**

1. On my Single's page I have used this comments_template('', true); to separate Trackback's & regular comments.
2. The Heading "Trackbacks for this post" shows up only if a post has trackbacks.

**Now the issue is, if the comments are paginated:**

1. On First page, the trackback are shown and below them the regular comments are shown along with older/newer links to paginated comments pages.
2. On deeper comments pages (e.g. /comment-page-2/) , no trackbacks are shown, however the title still appears.

Is there a way to hide the "Trackback title" on subsequent pages if there are no more trackbacks?